# Book for children/teens about a boy who had wings

Tags: story-identification, books

I’m looking for a book with illustrations about a boy who had wings. I remember that the ending was sad; he ran away. I read the book in French in 2012 or 2013. In the early chapters, the boy was a child, and there was a doctor. Then the boy grew older.

I’m not sure, but I remember a pool and lot of people looking at him. Maybe he was rich, or people were looking him because he had wings. He flew away to live the life that he was supposed to live, and I think he dies at the end. I found a writer, Edmond Hamilton, and I think he was the author, but it was adapted for young people.

I tried everything to find it and I saw people here helping for this kind of thing. @Jenayah I saw you answering someone who was looking for the same book and you asked if it was in French so if you have time, please answer this question. Thanks to you and anyone else who answers this question; thank you all. <3

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You've told us very little about the book you're looking for though. Please take a look at the check lists in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and then [edit] your question to add any further details that you can recall. In particular, it would be helpful to know the approximate year in which you read this book. It might also help if you added a link to the other question you mentioned.

Comment: Hello thanks you for your answer. I read the book in 2012 or 2013. There were illustrations at the first chapters the boy was a children there were a doctor then he become more older. I’m not sure but I remember a pool and lot of people looking at him maybe he was rich or people were looking him because he had wings and he fly away to live the life that he was supposed to live and I think he dies at the end. I find a writer Edmond Hamilton and I think it was his creation but was adapted for young people.I hope you will understand:)

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies the story you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if the only answers posted are incorrect, please indicate that with a comment so we know to keep looking. Thanks.

Comment: We've closed your question as a Duplicate, but please don't feel like it's a censure. It's a good question, just one we've had asked before. :-D [I asked it myself](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/249940/).

Answer (score 8):

The story you've described is ***[He That Hath Wings](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?61228)***, a piece of short fiction by Edmond Hamilton, first published in the [July 1938 edition](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61985) of *Weird Tales*.

[This article](http://adventuresfantastic.com/he-that-hath-wings/) describes the story in considerable detail:

> The story concerns a boy, David Rand, whose parents were caught in what is only described as an electrical explosion, but they were exposed to some unidentified form of radiation.  David’s father dies before his is born, and his mother dies a few hours after his birth.  **The boy has some odd growths on his back.  The doctor who did the delivery has them x-rayed and discovers they are wings that haven’t yet broken the skin.**
>
> **Trying to keep David from becoming a freak to be exploited by the media, he retires to an island with David, a nurse/housekeeper, and a caretaker. David’s wings unfurl, and when he is twelve he begins to fly. He wants to leave the island, but the doctor doesn’t want him to until he is older. He is restricted to flying above the island, although his heart is with the migratory birds.  The doctor dies unexpectedly when David is in his late teens.**
>
> **David takes to the skies and begins to follow migratory birds. His life passes pleasantly, and he is happy.**  He sleeps in trees, and during the night, he raids orchards. Sometimes he flies above cities and wonders how people can live so closed in and crammed together.
>
> One night, as David is approaching an orchard, he hears a loud noise and feels a searing pain in his head. He loses consciousness. When he awakens, he finds himself in a hospital bed, a doctor and a beautiful young woman standing over him.
>
> Her name is Ruth, and she tells him that he was shot by one of their servants who was hunting a hawk that had been catching their chickens. He mistook David for the hawk in the dark. Part of the shotgun blast got David on the side of the head. He is expected to make a full recovery.
>
> You can probably guess how this one is going to turn out. While he is recovering, David falls in love with Ruth. He asks her to marry him. She says she won’t because she doesn’t want her husband to be a freak. She wants him to be like all the other women’s husbands. David finally agrees to have his wings amputated.
>
> At first he doesn’t miss his wings. He and Ruth are happy in the small house her father built for them, and he works in his father-in-law’s factory. Then the weather changes, and David hears the call of geese migrating one night. For the next few years he tells himself eh doesn’t miss his wings.
>
> Then they start to grow back. David rationalizes not having them re-amputated until they’ve fully grown out. Meanwhile Ruth tells him she’s pregnant. Shortly after his son is born, without any wings, David still hasn’t told Ruth about the wings. The new ones are small and weak, nothing like his original pair. He slips out one night to have them amputated.
>
> The wind is blowing, and on impulse David takes off his shirt to flap his wings. He doesn’t think they will lift him off the ground. But they do. David takes to the air, and as he soars, he realizes that this is the life he really wants. To soar free above the ground. He flies away with some migratory birds, feeling like he has awoken from a dream. As the birds fly, they cross over the ocean. David continues to fly with them, even though his wings are weak and tiring. He goes to his death in the waves feeling satisfied with how his life is ending because he is doing what he was born to do.

Not sure which specific book you would've read this in, but it might've been [*Mutants*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?262475) (1988) (aka [*Young Mutants*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?55807)) edited by Asimov, Greenberg, and Waugh.

Failing that, it's probably one of the other books listed in the 'publications' section of [the ISFDB page](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?61228) for the story.

You can read [the full story](https://archive.org/details/Weird_Tales_v32n01_1938-07/page/n69/mode/2up?view=theater) at the Internet Archive.

Comment: Good morning, yes I am sure it’s, the he that hath wings by Hamilton but the book that I read was made for youngest publique there were illustrations but the story was the same so I think it’s the exacte same story and someone juste adopte the original book for children, teenagers. Thanks you for taking you time to answer very nice :)

Comment: @Otabek: Don't forget to accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.